# Skybox from file at runtime in Unity: Error assigning 2D texture to CUBE texture property '_Tex': Dimensions must match

Tags: unity, cubemap, skybox

I'm downloading skyboxes at runtime, and then I'd like to set them as the current scene's Skybox.

After I successfully downloaded the desired cubemap into the ApplicationData folder, I'm trying to set them as skybox as following:

```
private void LoadSkybox(string path)
{
    var skyboxMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Skybox/Cubemap"));

    var skyboxData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    var skyboxTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    skyboxTexture.LoadImage(skyboxData); //..this will auto-resize the texture dimensions, if I understood it correctly

    skyboxMaterial.SetTexture("_Tex", skyboxTexture);

    RenderSettings.skybox = skyboxMaterial;
    DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment();
}
```

The problem is that it fails to do so, because:

> Error assigning 2D texture to CUBE texture property '_Tex': Dimensions must match
>
> UnityEngine.Material:SetTexture (string,UnityEngine.Texture)

The loaded texture's dimensions are 700x525, and the file isn't corrupted or anything.

If I

- manually import it,
- set the type to cubemap,
- create a Skybox/Cubemap material based on it
- set this new material as the scene's skybox...

It works just fine.

Why doesn't this work?

What other solutions are there?

Comment: Why are you using a Texture2D variable when you want to use a Cubemap?

Comment: I thought that Cubemap is deprecated and Texture2D is just fine as well. So it isn't?

Comment: What leads you to believe this?

Comment: I can't really find it now, maybe I messed up and only the documentation was deprecated.

Comment: @DMGregory I've managed to load it into a Cubemap with the SetPixels method, but the problem is that every square is flipped vertically.

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to ask about that.

Comment: I think I will ask a new one, and post an answer to this. Maybe someone will find it useful.